# Populate target_id in REST result

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8 like an API, headless Drupal, and when creating a content type that has a reference to another "Content type", the resulting JSON has a "target_id" filed but with no data populated of the content that is referenced.
Is there a way to do that that you can point that? 
Thanks!